# php tick box array for email form

Tags: php, email

i'm new to stackoverflow but after trying a number of way i can't get my head around this email form. The form works fine but i've tried to add 4 optional tick boxes so the client can tick so we know which package they're interested in. I think i've got the front end setup properly:

```
      <p><label for="author">Full Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_name" class="details" tabindex="1" /></p>

<p><label for="telephone">Telephone:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_telephone" class="details" tabindex="2" /></p>

<p><label for="email">E-mail:</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="cf_email" class="details" tabindex="3" /></p>

<p><label for="package">Package Type:</label><br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="cf_package[]" class="package" value="Business English Classes" tabindex="4" /> Business English Classes<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="cf_package[]" class="package" value="English Conversation Classes" tabindex="4" /> English Conversation Classes<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="cf_package[]" class="package" value="Exam Preparation Classes" tabindex="4" /> Exam Preparation Classes<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="cf_package[]" class="package" value="Writing Skills Classes" tabindex="4" /> Writing Skills Classes
</p>

        <p><label for="message">Questions/Comments:</label><br />
<textarea type="text" name="cf_message" class="questions" tabindex="8"></textarea></p>

<p style="padding-top:10px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" tabindex="9" /> <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Clear" class="button" tabindex="10" /></p>
```

My backend script is as follows:

```
<code><?php
// get all values from form and remove spaces before/after values
$field_name = trim($_POST['cf_name']);
$field_telephone = trim($_POST['cf_telephone']);
$field_email = trim($_POST['cf_email']);
$field_package = trim($_POST['cf_package']);
$field_message = trim($_POST['cf_message']);

  $mail_to = 'theenglishbeehive@gmail.com';

 $subject = 'Enquiry from '.$field_name;

// check if user input own e-mail -> generate headers and send mail
if ($field_email && $field_message)
 {
 // generate body of message
   $body_message  = "From: ".$field_name."\n";
   $body_message .= "Telephone: ".$field_telephone."\n";
   $body_message .= "E-mail: ".$field_email."\n";
   $body_message .= "Package Type: ".$field_package."\n";
   $body_message .= "Questions/Comments: ".$field_message;

   $headers  = "From: ".$field_email."\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$field_email."\n";
   $headers .= "Return-Path: ".$field_email."\n";
   $headers .= "X-Priority: 3 (Normal)\n";
   // send email
$mail_status =  mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


         }

         // success ?
        if ($mail_status)
        {
        ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'enquiry-sent.php';
</script>
       <?php
      }
    else
     {
    ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to    theenglishbeehive@gmail.com');
    window.location = 'index.php';
</script>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   </code>
```

Hopefully i've got this showing properly on the website too.

Comment: You forgot to ask your actual question. So far i see alot of code and what you are doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected 'package' will be sent to the server as an array, not as a string, because you're using the array notation ([]) and using checkboxes, people can select multiple packages.

You might want to convert the array to a comma-separated string and show which packageS the user selected:

```
$field_package = implode(', ', $_POST['cf_package']);
```

and then:

```
$body_message .= "Package Type(s): ".$field_package."\n";
```

If only a single option should be allowed to be selected, you might consider using a radio-button in stead of checkboxes.